# Logic problem with the simple nested loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying a simple nested loop. For each digit in num1, the inner loop should run.
For the following numbers, ideally the output should be:

```
num1 digit: 7
num2 digit: 4
num2 digit: 3
num1 digit: 5
num2 digit: 4
num2 digit: 3
```

But it does not run the inner loop for the second time, so it only prints this:

```
num1 digit: 7
num2 digit: 4
num2 digit: 3
num1 digit: 5
```

what's wrong with the logic?

```
num1 = 57;
num2 = 34;
while ( num1 > 0 ) {

    digit1 = num1 % 10;
    num1 = num1 / 10;
    System.out.println("num1 digit: " + digit1);

    while (num2 > 0 ) {
        digit2 = num2 % 10;
        System.out.println("num2 digit: " + digit2);
        num2 = num2 / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: `num2 = num2 / 10;` Modifies `num2` so after the inner loop runs once, `num2` is zero for subsequent iterations of the outer loop. You need to reset it after the inner loop. Or use a temp variable: `int temp = num2; while (temp > 0).....`

Comment: Note, another option is to use a `for` loop: `for (int i = num2; i > 0; i /= 10) {digit2 = i % 10; System.out.println("num2 digit: " + digit2);}` This also creates a temp variable (`i`) but is a bit more compact.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks a lot, your comment was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the num2 inside the loop, try with something like:

```
num1 = 57;
num2 = 34;
int tempNum2 = num2;
while ( num1 > 0 ) {

    digit1 = num1 % 10;
    num1 = num1 / 10;
    System.out.println("num1 digit: " + digit1);

    while (tempNum2 > 0 ) {
        digit2 = tempNum2 % 10;
        System.out.println("num2 digit: " + digit2);
        tempNum2 = tempNum2 / 10;
    }
    tempNum2 = num2;
}
```

Comment: You declare `tempNum2` with `int` twice as a minor fix.

Comment: One more minor thing is you still are using `num2` in the second `while` loop at `num2 % 10`, the code will run but print incorrect results.

Comment: @Nexevis well, I should stop answering today, my brain is out of service. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-declare the num2 integer within the while loop for num1 > 0 to run the num2 > 0 again;

```
int num1 = 57;
int num2 = 34;
while ( num1 > 0 ) {
    digit1 = num1 % 10;
    num1 = num1 / 10;
    System.out.println("num1 digit: " + digit1);

    while (num2 > 0 ) {
         digit2 = num2 % 10;
         System.out.println("num2 digit: " + digit2);
         num2 = num2 / 10;
    }

    //Add here
    num2 = 34;
 }
```

Comment: This solution is not optimal as it requires `34` to be hardcoded into the code twice.  `34` is most likely not always going to be the value, which is why a temporary variable is ideal.